# How exclude topbar overflow content?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, flexbox

please, helpe me, when my main content is overflowed, the overflow is displayed from the top menu, is this behavior normal? Is there a way to exclude the top menu from this behavior? It happens that when I navigate between pages that do not overflow, the main menu alters the size which makes it unpleasant to look at.
[image]

Este es mi código:

```
<div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <div className='container' style={{ marginBottom: '50px' }}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Simulador />} />
            <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='/information' element={<Information />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div >
```

Comment: try adding a fixed width to your element and using overflow: hidden for it. 
if you share your codes then I can send an answer for your problem.